# GPS on Ionic: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am returning the address of a GPS application this way

```
 geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status) {
    if (status = google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (data[0] != null) {
        alert("address is: " + data[0].formatted_address);
        $scope.$apply(function() {  
        $scope.addresses = data[0].formatted_address;
        //$scope.apply();
        })
      } else {
        alert("No address available");
      }
    }
  })
```

I am getting the scope variable this way:

```
<p>address: {{addresses}}</p>
```

When I deploy the app I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'addresses' of undefined
Please what could be wrong.

Comment: is this code running inside a controller?

Comment: Try to debug your code using Chrome developer tools or firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.addresses = "";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(your_lat, your_lng);
var request = {
    latLng : latlng    
 };
 geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status){
      if(status = google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
          if(data[0] != null){                      
              $scope.$apply(function(){    
                   $scope.addresses = data[0].formatted_address;
              });
           } else {
                  alert("No address available");
           }
      }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $scope variable you pass to the geocode callback function. You are overriding the controller's $scope variable.

And make sure that controller declaration injects a $scope variable

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   // do your thing
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the $scope.apply();

Comment: no, I mean in this line of code -->  geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status,$scope) {

remove the $scope passed param from here. And make sure it is added to the controller function like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like '$scope' is missing from the list of dependency injected params in your controller.

```
angular.module('MyGeoCoderControllerModule', [])
.controller('GeoCoderController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


 }
]);
```